# How do I see contents of this Swift class object in Xcode after breakpoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to both Xcode and Swift (...and serious Swift programming) and am hoping someone can help me figure out how to view / access the values of this class object.

I have this code in my ViewController.swift for invoking my REST API (via AWS API Gateway) and am attempting to print `result` to the console. Clearly, all I'm doing here is printing the address of the class object:

```
@IBAction func userInvokeApi(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("You clicked invoke api...")
    let client = SVTLambdaGateClient.default()
    client.calcGet(operand2: "3", _operator: "+", operand1: "5").continueWith{ (task: AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task?.error {
            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

        if let result = task?.result {
            // Do something with result
            print("The result is... \(result)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Here's what prints:

```
You clicked invoke api...
The result is... <AmplifyRestApiTest.Empty: 0x600002020770> {
}
```

(where AmplifyRestApiTest is the name of my Xcode project. Though I'm **NOT** using AWS Amplify to build this project; mainly because I've run into problems using it.)

I do have this `Empty` class in `Empty.swift` that is part of the API Gateway generated iOS Swift SDK:

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore

@objcMembers
public class Empty : AWSModel {
    public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
    var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]`
        return params
    }
}
```

Now, when I set a breakpoint on the print statement this is what I see:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone please tell me why I don't see the values relating to this object? What's the strategy for unpacking this API response??

I know that I'm invoking the REST API successfully because I can see (via Cloudwatch logs) that it's returning the result to the Client. So this post is just my attempt to access the corresponding Object.

Another detail: I'm using an API Gateway generated iOS Swift SDK and I followed all of the [tutorial instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) for using the SDK in my project.

Answer (score 0):

use lldb command po to print the object.

```
(lldb) po @"lunar"
lunar
(lldb) p @"lunar"
(NSString *) $13 = 0x00007fdb9d0003b0 @"lunar"
```

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know about lldb until now... or know that there was a waiting cursor for me in the debug console... so thank you! And I can see that your example comes from [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/). But I don't understand that example because all it does it print the string. And `po result` and `p result` don't seem to show me anything new. I just added a new screenshot above.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest going over the docs here...
https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSCore#getting-started-with-swift

Did you import appropriate headers?

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I don't know the answer to that question... but I can say the only headers I'm importing to my ViewController are UIKit and AWSMobileClient. I just quickly added AWSCore, compiled, and ran.. and the breakpoint for `result` appears the same way. I will RTFM... :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've configured my project correctly and this all comes down to understanding Swift. I followed an AWS API Gateway tutorial for creating a REST API. I verified that it works, then I generated an iOS Swift SDK and followed the directions to use that in my simple iOS application. (Though it has Amplify in the project name I am **not** using Amplify.) I'm invoking the REST API and I can see (via Cloudwatch) that it's successfully returning the result to the Client. So this post is just my attempt to access the corresponding Object.